# How to deal with JSON when a key is missing sometimes

Tags: javascript, json

I'm reading a json file and have found sometimes there is a new value which I want to save. sometimes it's not present. 
How can I deal with this ?

```
"parameters": {
    "dateTime": "2017-10-23T19:23:39Z",
    "agentId": "7771",
    "rp.app_auth": "user:password",
}
```

The AgentId is the value that appears sometimes which I want to capture.

```
"parameters": {
    "dateTime": "2017-12-27T18:47:15Z",
    "rp.app_auth": "user:password"
}
```

Sometimes it's not there.

Comment: What do you mean "How to deal with it?". Simply check to see if it's present, and if it's not put in null or some default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator to check if a key exist.

```js
const obj = {
  "parameters": {
    "dateTime": "2017-10-23T19:23:39Z",
    "agentId": "7771",
    "rp.app_auth": "user:password",
  }
}

if ("agentId" in obj.parameters) {
  console.log(true);
}
```

Or use `hasOwnProperty('key')` method of an object.

```
if (obj.parameters.hasOwnProperty('agentId')) {
    console.log(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for checking a key that whether it's present or not you can use javascript's `obj.hasOwnProperty('key')` function to determine it.
for e.g

```
var obj=JSON.parse('{"key":"value"}');
obj.hasOwnProperty('key'); //returns true
obj.hasOwnProperty('key2'); //returns false

if(obj.hasOwnProperty('key')){
    //do something with the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a default value for it. The following line of code will work this way: it's going to coerce the first value that it can convert to true. If you do have a parameters.agentId, then myVar will get its value, if you don't have it, then parameters.agentId it's gonna to be undefined and coerced to false, then myVar it's going to be your defalutValue, because it will be coerced to true.

```
var myVar = parameters.agentId || "defaultValue";
```

That is the best way to handle a parameter that you are not sure it's going to be available.